# Iterate through Dictionary in order

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary in the order I have created the dictionary for example, I want it to print name in this order. Right now it prints in random order.

Order I want :ExtraClick, AutoClick, PackCookies, BakeStand, GirlScouts

code:

```
self.how_many_buildings = {'ExtraClick': 0,
                               'AutoClick': 0,
                               'PackCookies': 0,
                               'BakeStand': 0,
                               'GirlScouts': 0}
for name in self.how_many_buildings:
    print(name)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 4):

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain order for dictionaries

```
from collections import OrderedDict

self.how_many_buildings = OrderedDict(('ExtraClick', 0),
                                      ('AutoClick', 0),
                                      ('PackCookies', 0),
                                      ('BakeStand', 0),
                                      ('GirlScouts': 0))
for name in self.how_many_buildings:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionaries` ***do not have order*** and hence you require external classes that can handle the order too. Something like [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) available in  [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module which forms a wrapper class on the base `dict` class, providing extra functionalities along with all the other basic operations of `dict`.

Example :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict( [('a',1) , ('b',2) , ('c',3)] )
>>> for key in d: 
        print(key)    
=>  a
    b
    c
```

Comment: When you create an `OrderedDict` from a dictionary literal as shown, you don't really know what order the items will end up in because the **argument** is unordered. To avoid this you should use an ordered iterable like a `list`, `tuple`, or generator to control the order the returned dictionay's contents have.

Comment: @martineau : have updated